# 'int' object is not subscriptable python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I'm new to python and reading a excel file. Which I'm again inserting into an array.
But I'm getting an error

```
 File "SPD_new.py", line 57, in <module>
   spd_record.transdate = str(mapping_record[4])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Below is my code:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("SPD.xlsx")
worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
mapping_records = {}
for worksheet_name in worksheets:
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
    mapping_record = MappingRecord()
    if worksheet_name == "NB":
        for curr_row in range(0,worksheet.nrows):
            mapping_record = worksheet.row(curr_row)
            mapping_records[0] = mapping_record
            print worksheet_name
            print mapping_record[1]
            for mapping_record in mapping_records:
                print "In If...."
                spd_record = MappingRecord()
                spd_record.merchantid = "00002269"
                spd_record.transdate = mapping_record[4]
                spd_record.amount = float(mapping_record[5])
                spd.erocode = None
                spd.scno = None
                mapping_records[spd_record[8]] = spd_record
                print spd_record
    elif worksheet_name == "CD":
        for curr_row in range(0,worksheet.nrows):
            mapping_records[0] = mapping_record
            print worksheet_name
print "Read SPD File....."
```

Comment: Note that your traceback doesn't quite fit your actual code as posted; you are missing a `str()` call in the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name `mapping_record` for two different things in your code:

```
# a custom object
mapping_record = MappingRecord()

# as a loop variable
for mapping_record in mapping_records:
```

Inside the loop it is one of the *keys* in the `mapping_records` dictionary, and your keys are integers, so when you try to use `mapping_record[4]` you get an exception.

Perhaps you meant to loop over the *values* in the dictionary? In that case use:

```
for mapping_record in mapping_records.values():
```